# Processing nested elements using XML::Twig

Tags: perl, xml-twig

```
<cov>
    <item>
        <valo></valo>
        <valt></valt>
        <valtr></valtr>
    </item>             
    <item>
        <valo></valo>
        <valt></valt>
        <valtr></valtr>
    </item>             
    <item>
        <valo></valo>
        <valt></valt>
        <valtr></valtr>
    </item>             
</cov>
```

I'm trying to use twig to loop through valo and valtr for each item - how can I do this?

I have this so far, but inside the subroutine how can I then specify the right node "valo"?

```
my $t = XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers => {'cov/item' => \&item });
my $url;
$t->parse($fileContent);

sub item {
    my ($t, $item) = @_;
    print $item->text . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a handler that shows a way to inspect the children of the `cov/item` nodes:

```
sub item {
    my ($t, $item) = @_;

    my @kids = $item->children;
    for my $kid ( @kids ) {
        warn "valo is:  " . $kid->text if $kid->name eq q{valo};
        warn "valtr is: " . $kid->text if $kid->name eq q{valtr};
    }
}
```

Another approach is to use `findnodes( )` and Twig's XPath-like syntax to locate the elements:

```
my $t = XML::Twig->new->parse( $fileContent );
for my $node ( $t->findnodes( '//valo' ) ) {
    warn "valo is: " . $node->text;
}
```

... Or for full XPath syntax, use XML::Twig::XPath instead:

```
my $t = XML::Twig::XPath->new->parse( $fileContent );
for my $node ( $t->findnodes( '//valo | //valtr' ) ) {
    warn "valo is:   " . $node->text if $node->name eq q{valo};
    warn "valtr is:  " . $node->text if $node->name eq q{valtr};
}
```

See the [`XML::Twig` docs](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.38/Twig.pm) for details of the methods used here.

Comment: instead of doing this loop for each element shouldn't we be using xpath somehow?

Comment: I added some xpath alternatives.